# Bar chart in IPython; Not recognizing one of my columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm making a bar chart showing the WAR rating per years played for baseball players. I am trying to label the bar chart as Player Name (years played). Here is my code:

```
#Generate full names for the players: player name (years played)
full_name = []

for player, years in zip(war_data['Player'].values, war_data['yrs'].values):
    full_name.append(player + " (" + str(years) + ")")

war_data["Full_Name"] = array(full_name)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,12))
```

My data set is called war_data. It outputs correctly when I input `war_data.head()` and is organized as follows:

```
     Player                yrs   WAR     WAR_per_yearsplayed
0    Babe Ruth+         22   183.8       8.354545
785  Charlie Ferguson    4   32.1        8.025000
2    Walter Johnson+    21   165.6       7.885714
15   Kid Nichols+       15   116.4       7.760000
1    Cy Young+          22   168.4       7.654545
```

The error I get is:

```
KeyError: u'no item named Player'
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

EDIT: Here is the full traceback:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a2cfa6bc215d> in <module>()
      2 full_name = []
      3 
----> 4 for player, years in zip(war_data['Player'].values, war_data['yrs'].values):
      5     full_name.append(player + " (" + str(years) + ")")
      6 

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   2001             # get column
   2002             if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2003                 return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2004 
   2005             # duplicate columns

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pandas\core\generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item)
    665             return cache[item]
    666         except Exception:
--> 667             values = self._data.get(item)
    668             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
    669             cache[item] = res

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pandas\core\internals.pyc in get(self, item)
   1653     def get(self, item):
   1654         if self.items.is_unique:
-> 1655             _, block = self._find_block(item)
   1656             return block.get(item)
   1657         else:

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pandas\core\internals.pyc in _find_block(self, item)
   1933 
   1934     def _find_block(self, item):
-> 1935         self._check_have(item)
   1936         for i, block in enumerate(self.blocks):
   1937             if item in block:

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pandas\core\internals.pyc in _check_have(self, item)
   1940     def _check_have(self, item):
   1941         if item not in self.items:
-> 1942             raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
   1943 
   1944     def reindex_axis(self, new_axis, method=None, axis=0, copy=True):

KeyError: u'no item named Player'
```

Comment: I suspect this is actually a `pandas` issue

Comment: also, please include the full backtrace

Comment: Probably there's whitespace you don't see.  `print war_data.columns`.

Comment: @DSM, that was it! There is a space. It's `'Player '` not `'Player'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Moved from comments.]

Probably there's whitespace you don't see.  `print war_data.columns` to check.  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A ": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
>>> df
   A   B
0   1  2
1   2  3
2   3  4

[3 rows x 2 columns]
>>> df.columns
Index([u'A ', u'B'], dtype='object')
>>> df["A"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
KeyError: u'no item named A'
```